# Symmetry problem with the CSS I apply to an element on the right of my navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to decrease the space between my different social networks and by making :

`margin: 2px;` or `padding: 2px;`

It doesn't apply any change: how to apply a change between my different icons for my social networks please?
I would like to reduce the spacing between my 3 icons, here is a screen to illustrate my words, if you did not understand even if I think I have correctly explained the problem I will answer in comment, thank you in advance (If you have understood and you want to help me I am interested if you have explanations, I am trying to improve and it's been a few days that I block on this problem): **The screen to illustrate my words:** https://prnt.sc/13n7pss

If you see other things wrong in my code like this I'm interested, I'm a beginner and I don't necessarily have the best ways to develop so if you think I can improve it don't hesitate to tell me etc. Thank you very much

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

</head>
<body>

    <header class="topbar">
        <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html"></a>
        <nav>
            <div class="middle">
                <a href="invite.html">Invite</a>
                <a href="commands.html">Commands</a>
                <a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a>
                <a href="premium.html">Premium</a>
                <a href="support.html">Support</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/github.png"/></a>
                <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/32/000000/discord-logo.png"/></a>
                <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/32/000000/twitter.png"/></a>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="circuit">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dark">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dark">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dark">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="circuit">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="flex">
                <img class="img" src="img/white.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html">
            </div>


            <div class="copyright">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="product">
            <li><b>Product</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="resources">
            <li><b>Resources</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="business">
            <li><b>Business</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="design">
            designed with  <span style="color: red;">&#10084;</span> by <span style="color: #065299;">My Discord Id</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="social"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/github.png" /></div>
    <div class="social"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/twitter.png" /></div>
    <div class="social"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/discord-logo.png" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
}

.circuit {
    background-image: url(img/background.svg);
    background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
    padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
    background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
    padding: 192px 16px;
}

.topbar {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.topbar nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar nav a {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.topbar nav a:hover, .topbar nav a.active {
    color: #000;
}

.right {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}

.header-logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25vh;
}

h1 {
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
}

  #footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr .6fr .6fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "logo product resources business";
}
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1px;
}
  
  .flex {
    display: flex;
}
  
  #footer li a {
    color: rgb(22,145,176);
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-area: logo;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .img {
    padding-top: .5rem;
    width: 25vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
  .logo h4 {
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
  
  .copyright {
    padding-top: .3rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(97,97,97);
}
  
  .product {
    grid-area: product;
    font-size: 20px;
}
  
  .resources {
    grid-area: resources;
    font-size: 20px;
}
  
  .business {
    grid-area: business;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.social { 
    grid-area: social;
    padding-left: .3rem;
    padding-bottom: .3rem; 
    font-size: .6em;
}

.design {
    grid-area: design;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go...**

Add this to your CSS:

```
.right a {
  margin-right: -10%;
}
```

If you want to decrease white space between your icons, you need to set negative margin-right (not positive!). Positive margin-right will do exactly the opposite that you want to achieve.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
}

.circuit {
  background-image: url(img/background.svg);
  background-color: rgba(62, 62, 62, 1);
  padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  padding: 192px 16px;
}

.topbar {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.topbar nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar nav a {
  color: #9F9F9F;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.topbar nav a:hover,
.topbar nav a.active {
  color: #000;
}

.right {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}

.right a {
  margin-right: -10%;
}

.header-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#footer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr .6fr .6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo product resources business";
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 8%;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#footer li a {
  color: rgb(22, 145, 176);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  grid-area: logo;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.img {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  width: 25vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo h4 {
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.copyright {
  padding-top: .3rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
}

.product {
  grid-area: product;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.resources {
  grid-area: resources;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.business {
  grid-area: business;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.social {
  grid-area: social;
  padding-left: .3rem;
  padding-bottom: .3rem;
  font-size: .6em;
}

.design {
  grid-area: design;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="topbar">
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html"></a>
    <nav>
      <div class="middle">
        <a href="invite.html">Invite</a>
        <a href="commands.html">Commands</a>
        <a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a>
        <a href="premium.html">Premium</a>
        <a href="support.html">Support</a>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/github.png" /></a>
        <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/32/000000/discord-logo.png" /></a>
        <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/32/000000/twitter.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```